# SSIS: OleDB a Excel problema en una columna varchar(1000)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

Al exportar desde una base de datos SQL a Excel en SSIS, tengo problema en una columna en SQL que es `VARCHAR(1000)`, he tratado de pasarlo a `Unicode_Ntext`, pero me sale el error:

> [Excel Destination [84]] Error: An error occurred while setting up a
>   binding for the "observacion" column. The binding status was
>   "DT_NTEXT".

Comment: Intenta trabajarlo como .csv y una vez ahí guardar como excel :D

Answer (score 0):

Lastimosamente cuando en el excel de destino se crean las columnas que recibirán los datos, se toman en cuenta las primeras 8 filas, si ninguno de esos 8 registros sobrepasa los 255 caracteres para la columna en cuestión, esta quedará con un máximo de 255 para el resto de la tabla. Esto es un bug de EXCEL que solo se puede resolver de un par de formas:

1. Que el archivo destino ya esté creado y tenga un registro "temporal" donde tengas un texto mayor a 255 caracteres en esa columna.
2. Modifica tu set de datos para que uno de los registros con mas caracteres venga siempre entre los primeras 8 filas.

Como sugerencia: recuerdo que había una forma de modificar en el registro de windows el numero de filas que se utiliza para asignarle el tipo y largo a las columnas, pero nunca lo he hecho. Tocaría buscar en google.